# Find Max value from JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON like this

```
    {
    "name": "Reporta",
    "assignments": [
        {
          "person_id": 638020,
          "hours_logged": 25.5
        },
        {
          "person_id": 638020,
          "hours_logged": 35.5
        }
    ]
    }
```

I have to find the first person id from assignments array and i followed this code

```
    JObject lp_ask = JObject.Parse(response_json);
    int assignee = (int)lp_ask["assignments"][0]["person_id"];
```

But now I have to find the person_id who logged max hours from the array.
I can do a foreach loop and then can find max value, but is any direct option available?

Comment: Why not converting it to an object first then do `LINQ` on that?

Comment: Since the object model mapping is not feasible for me (presence of large number of elements in JSON model). The attached JSON is a part of whole JSON only . Also the JSON contains lot of dynamic entries depends on request type

Comment: So just parse the part you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way would be to deserialize to a set of static classes, but if you don't want or cannot do that - you can query over raw JSON too:

```
var person = lp_ask["assignments"]
    .OrderByDescending(c => c["hours_logged"].Value<double>())        
    .Select(c => c["person_id"].Value<int>())
    .First();
```

Comment: Quick n' dirty.

Comment: This is so good I could kiss you! but what wit social distancing and all.. I'll just say thanks. 

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this issue on database level using SQL Server JSON support (for SQL Server 2016 and later)

Here is the sample query I used for your requirement

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '
    {
    "name": "Reporta",
    "assignments": [
        {
          "person_id": 638020,
          "hours_logged": 25.5
        },
        {
          "person_id": 638020,
          "hours_logged": 35.5
        }
    ]
    }
'
select 
    person_id, hours_logged
from (
    select
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.name') AS [name], 
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.assignments['+convert(varchar(2),i)+'].person_id')as person_id,
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.assignments['+convert(varchar(2),i)+'].hours_logged') AS hours_logged,
        row_number() over (order by JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.assignments['+convert(varchar(2),i)+'].hours_logged') desc) as rn
    from dbo.NumbersTable(0,10,1) n
) t
where rn = 1
```

Please note that I used a [numbers table SQL function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx) to query each node under assignments.

I sort the sub-rows for assignments by using Row_Number() function and in main select use filter criteria for row_number() value as 1

Output is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a POCO object (Person_Id, Hours_Logged) that you can deserialize to:

```
var reports = Jsonconvert.Deserialize<YourObjectName>(response_json);
```

Then you can use LINQ max function:

```
var personWithMostHoursLogged = reports.Max(x => x.Hours_Logged);
```

EDIT: this may help you:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> DeserializeToDictionary(string input)
{
      dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(input);
      return (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
}
```

Comment: Since the object model mapping is not feasible for me (presence of large number of elements in JSON model). The attached JSON is a part of whole JSON only . Also the JSON contains lot of dynamic entries depends on request type

Comment: How about pushing those two fields you're extracting into a dictionary and then using Linq?  Or... you could deserialize into a dynamic object - which from a JSON object is effectively a dictionary, and then search for the keys you want?

Comment: Is it possible to get a dictionary without foreach iteration ?

Comment: See edit, however, be aware that LINQ enumerates the list to get the max result anyway.

Comment: BTW, I like Evk's answer better if you want an easy solution.

Comment: Yes something similar i was expecting

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);  
    var assignments = JsonConvert.DeserilizeObject<Assignment[]>(lp_ask["assignments"].ToString());
    var assignment = assignments.OrderByDescending(i => i.hours_logged).FirstOrDefault();
}

private class Assignment
{
    public double hours_logged { get; set; }

    public int person_id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it this way, for example if you want to find the maximum value of some token in a json string simply do the following:

```
int max = JObject.Parse(strJSON)
                .SelectTokens("$..recordDataNumber")
                .Select(s => s.Value<int>())
                .Max();
```